# Как создать словарь с полями ввода в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, tkinter

У меня есть кусок кода, который создаёт в цикле поля ввода и размещает их в 3 столбцах:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
pos = 0
x = 50
y = 50 

try:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(9):
            letter = alphabet[pos]

            label = Label(text=letter)
            entry = Entry()

            label.place(x=x, y=y)
            entry.place(x=x + 30, y=y, width=30)

            globals()['label_' + letter] = label
            globals()['letter_' + letter] = entry

            pos += 1
            y += 50

        y = 50
        x += 100

except IndexError:
    pass
```

Х и Y - координаты полей ввода и надписей. В результате получается такая штука:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Беда в том, что мне нужно как-то обращаться к этим полям ввода после их создания. Я читал на форумах, что создание таких переменных (letter_a, letter_b и т.д.) в цикле - плохая идея и нужно создавать их с помощью словаря.

**Как можно создать словарь, который будет хранить введенные в поля ввода символы?** Я просто не понимаю как это сделать. Мне кажется, нужно, чтобы каждое  поле ввода было с уникальным именем, чтобы из него можно было взять заменяемый символ.

p.s. небольшое объяснение работы моей программы, если нужно: мне необходимо заменить в текстовом файле одни символы на другие. Например "а" на "g" и т.д. То есть в поле ввода я подставлю букву на которую хочу поменять тот или иной символ.

Comment: `ваш_словарь = {}` и `ваш_словарь[letter] = entry` и так далее

Comment: Но тот блок кода, который я выложил, создаёт эти поля ввода. То есть при запуске программы сначала создаются поля ввода, затем я вручную должен заполнить поля и затем нажать на кнопку "Change letters", после чего нужно записать те символы, которые есть в этих полях. То есть, как я понимаю, нужно считать содержимое полей ввода в **другом** цикле. Я не понимаю, как можно к ним обратиться из другой части программы.

Comment: `новый_letter = ваш_словарь[старый_letter].get()` и так далее http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но я не могу понять, как мне применить это на практике. Блок try только создаёт поля ввода. В него нельзя сразу вставлять словарь, который будет хранить заменяемые символы, так как их нужно ещё вставить.
То есть я запустил программу и создались поля ввода. После этого я подставляю новые символы в поля ввода и нажимаю на кнопку, после чего начинает работу функция, которая и должна прочитать все поля ввода и поменять символы в тексте. Но в этом блоке у все полей одно имя - entry. Поправьте меня, если я ошибся или чего то не понимаю.

Comment: @Mark, не важно какое имя, вы всё равно будете обращаться к словарю по ключу.

Answer (score 2):

А в чём у вас сложность при создании словаря? Базовый пример:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

d = {"a": input(), "b": input()}

print d["a"] * d["b"]

# ввод 10
# ввод 34
# 340
```

В вашем случаи с полями ввода необходимо создать словарь до цикла `my_dict = {}`, а далее в цикле его заполнить `my_dict.update({label: entry})` - ключ и ссылка на ввод. Потом делаете замену в своём тексте:

```
for key in my_dict:
    my_text.replace(key, my_dict[key])
```